# Duplicate records after multiple table join in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `main_table` and it has the following records

| cust_id | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-30 |
| 10001 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-02-01 |

I have another table called `penalty_a_type` and it has the following records

| cust_id | start_date | end_date | penalty_a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-30 | 0 |
| 10001 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-02-01 | 0 |

I have another table called `penalty_b_type` and it has the following records

| cust_id | start_date | end_date | penalty_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-30 | 0 |
| 10001 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-02-01 | 4 |

I want to join these tables so that it looks like

| cust_id | start_date | end_date | penalty_a | penalty_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-30 | 0 | 0 |
| 10001 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-02-01 | 0 | 4 |

But I am getting the following table

| cust_id | start_date | end_date | penalty_a | penalty_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-30 | 0 | 0 |
| 10001 | 2022-12-01 | 2022-12-30 | 0 | 4 |
| 10001 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-02-01 | 0 | 0 |
| 10001 | 2023-01-03 | 2023-02-01 | 0 | 4 |

The code I have tried is

```
SELECT     m.cust_id,
           m.start_date,
           m.end_date,
           pa.penalty_a
           pb.penalty_b
    FROM main_table m
    JOIN penalty_a_type pa
    ON m.cust_id = pa.cust_id
    JOIN penalty_b_type pb
    ON m.cust_id = pb.cust_id
    GROUP BY m.cust_id, m.start_date, m.end_date, pa.penalty_a, pb.penalty_b
```

Comment: why do you have two cust_id duplicated?

Comment: I have unique values for all the records except a handful of rows that have duplicated records because of different start and end dates

Comment: so that's why do you get that result, because you are grouping with end_date and start_date so there are 2 different rows by those fields.

Comment: How should I proceed then?

Comment: check my answer, i remove a typo on the select, it should it work.

Comment: It is still showing duplicated records. The dates are important in this case

Comment: They are not duplicated records. The dates are differents.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT     m.cust_id,
       m.start_date,
       m.end_date,
       pa.penalty_a,
        pb.penalty_b
FROM main_table m
JOIN penalty_a_type pa
ON m.cust_id = pa.cust_id AND PA.START_DATE=m.START_DATE AND 
pa.END_DATE=m.END_DATE
JOIN penalty_b_type pb 
ON m.cust_id = pb.cust_id AND PB.START_DATE=m.START_DATE AND 
pb.END_DATE=m.END_DATE
```

Comment: Please could you elaborate on why this solves the issue ?

Comment: In my experience, if we have common columns in two tables, we have to include all common columns in joins of two or more tables; otherwise, some times we can get duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

`cust_id` on main table is duplicated.

If you care about the different start/end dates, then the result is fine. If you don't care, then remove it from group (and select)

```
SELECT     m.cust_id,
           pa.penalty_a
           pb.penalty_b
    FROM main_table m
    JOIN penalty_a_type pa
    ON m.cust_id = pa.cust_id
    JOIN penalty_b_type pb
    ON m.cust_id = pb.cust_id
    GROUP BY m.cust_id,pa.penalty_a, pb.penalty_b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with ROW_NUMBER and the following result as

```
with mt_cte as(SELECT m.cust_id,
       m.start_date,
       m.end_date,
       pa.penalty_a,
       pb.penalty_b,
row_number() over (partition by pa.penalty_a,pb.penalty_b) rn
FROM main_table m
JOIN penalty_a_type pa
ON m.cust_id = pa.cust_id
JOIN penalty_b_type pb
ON m.cust_id = pb.cust_id)
select * from mt_cte where rn = 1
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/cvg7jiRu

Comment: I got an error saying 
Window function row_number() requires window to be ordered, please add ORDER BY clause. For example SELECT row_number()(value_expr) OVER (PARTITION BY window_partition ORDER BY window_ordering) from table

Comment: I have mentioned the link & also my query runs successfully on Mysql. If you are working on SQLSever then it requires Order by Clause.